# Any DSL-based framework capable of dataset manipulation?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-batch, etl, dsl

I am looking for some Java-based solution to fit the following needs:

1. engine for execution of simple DSL
2. DSL which allows for dataset manipulation. for example: given I need some grouping operation. I dont want to code it in Java. I can just put down something like

   maxSalary = max(group(salaries, "amount"));

.. or easily extend it if group operator is not present.

3. mathematical functions should be present, or ready for extension

As far as I understand the thing I need is simple ETL. I suppose Informatica or Pentaho can do the job.
From the other hand, I try to understand if Spring Batch and Apache Camel can do it for me. Unfortunately I dont see any DSL for Spring Batch.

So could you please direct me to some framework or framework type to fit my needs?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't stick to normal Java server side development.
You can use Apache Pig to manipulate large data set. ( However, Apache Pig basically requires Hadoop environment. I recommend you to use some Cloud environment, like EMR.)

You can see similar syntax in the [Pig Latin Basics](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html)

Comment: Thank you, hiropon! Pig is for data stored in HDFS, i.e. on disk. Actually I dont think I need to store my tranformation results this way.But from the other hand it is a good suggestion as I can write scripts in Pig DSL without Java coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different frameworks/solutions you can use. I will name some of them so you can check their documents/quickstarts to see how it will fit your use-cases:

- Apache Flink (maybe overhead)

  - https://flink.apache.org/usecases.html
  - https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html
- Project Reactor

  - http://projectreactor.io
  - https://www.infoq.com/articles/reactor-by-example/

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav! Flink is interesting, but both projects do not allow for data manipulation with DSL. I.e. I want to make my data flow easily customizable without coding effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple solution, you could look at the Spring Expression Language which implement mechanisms that would allow you to perform "simple" data manipulation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Some basic mathematical functions and logical operators are natively provided. If needed, you could extend them by  enriching the Spring evaluation context with utilities (for example coming apache common maths).

That being said, this approach is very limited and may not be a good solution to build an extended DSL.

Hope this fits your needs !